# django error OperationalError at /admin/blog/post/

Tags: django, operationalerror

i get this error in simple django programme run.. 
OperationalError at /admin/blog/post/
no such table: blog_post

Comment: Please read [ask], if you were asked this question, what would you need to solve it?

Answer (score 8):

if django version >=django 1.7

```
python manage.py makemigrations 
python manage.py migrate
```

else

```
python manage.py schemamigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

so you need to migrate (map the model changes / new models into database tables) the changes so that your page works properly

Comment: @RemazeVs nice, dont forget to check as answer to show that the problem is solved ;)

Answer (score 3):

delete the migrations folder in app and then do :

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
```

it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You need to [run migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/) before you can do that operation. The necessary tables don't exist in your database (as described by the error).

Answer (score 0):

Check for a typo in the name of your Model. If you change your model name after makemigration and migrate, then it doesn't work and find the correct model name anymore.